# pytelegrambotapi: How to check button press?

Tags: python

I am making a bot using pytelegrambotapi,here is a sample code

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def send_key(message):
    buttons = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    btn_1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('1',callback_data='1')
    btn_2 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('2',callback_data='2')
    btn_3 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('3',callback_data='3')
    buttons.add(btn_1,btn_2,btn_3)
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    bot.send_message(chat_id,"text",reply_markup=buttons)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def callback(call):
    if call.data == '1':
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,text="1")
    if call.data == '2':
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,text="2")
    if call.data == '3':
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,text="3")
```

I handle the call, while processing each button, how can I check that another was pressed.
For example, I press button 1, how can I check that button 2 or 3 was previously pressed.
I could write to a variable after each button press, but I think there is a more correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if user pressed - just print to console 'User with chat_id ######### is pressed Button ##'
If you want to handle - call your function after *if call.data == '1':*.
And finally if you need to save user's action - define data structure like

```
# users = { 
#     12345678: ['1', '2', '3'],
#     22345678: ['4', '5', '6']
#     }
users = {}

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def callback(call):
    users[call.message.chat.id] = call.data
```

Or if you need all user's actions to be saved

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def callback(call):
# before append, an empty list should be created at /start command
# users[message.chat.id] = []
    users[call.message.chat.id].append(call.data)
```

Then print it to console or send to chat

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['/stats'])
def stats(message):
    st = ''
    for user in users:
        st = st + f'{str(user)} { "".join(users[user])}\n'
    print(st)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, st)
```